# Undo Markers in reopened fig fieldtrip

Tags: matlab, marker, figure

some time ago I have done topoplots of my MEG Data using `ft_topoplotTFR` and saved them as fig files. I have set the `cfg.marker = 'on'`.

Now I need the files but without the markers, because they just make the picture black and i cannot identify a lot. The markers are the Sensors. See in this picture:

[TopoplotTFR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU0z5.png)

The black little circles that cover the surface are the markers I am talking about. 
ft_topoplotTFR belongs to the fieldtrip toolbox and makes topoplots of Brain Data.

http://www.fieldtriptoolbox.org/reference/ft_topoplottfr

**Can I somehow change the marker settings in the figure if i just have the fig file?**

Comment: Please see: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

While we have no idea what `ft_topoplotTFR` is, the answer is going to follow more or less the same general steps: Load the figure, identify the plot objects, and modify their properties.

For example, we can generate a busy sample plot:

```
x = 0:0.05:10;
y1 = 5*rand(size(x));
y2 = 5*abs(sin(x));
plot(x, y1, '-d', x, y2, '-p');
savefig('test.fig');
close
```

[image: before]

We can then use [`openfig`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/openfig.html) to load the figure so we can access the plotted data:

```
myfig = openfig('test.fig');
% Child of a basic figure window with a plot is the axes object
myaxes = myfig.Children;
% Child(ren) of a generic axes with plotted data are the plot object(s)
myls = myaxes.Children;

set(myls, 'Marker', 'none');  % Turn off markers
```

Which gives us:

[image: yay]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response. I tried it but it gave me this ERROR: Error using matlab.graphics.primitive.Data/set
There is no Marker property on the Text class.        I edited the question so it's more clear what it's about  and added a picture.

Comment: If there are other graphics objects (patches, annotations, etc.) in the axes then you need to isolate the lineseries objects with something like [`findobj`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html) in order to avoid errors. Try `myls = findobj(myaxes.Children, 'Type', 'line');` instead.